# Stream manipulator with a simple Logger

Tags: c++, stream

So I have this simple C++ Logger class.

```
class Log{
public:
    Log(const int& msgLevel = 1){
        this->msgLevel = msgLevel;
    }

    template <class T>
    Log& operator<<(const T& v){
        if (msgLevel<=level) {
            std::cout << v;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~Log(){

    }

    static int level;
    int msgLevel;
};

int Log::level = 1;
```

I can use it like this:

```
Log(1)<<"My debug info: "<<otherVariable;
```

The problem is when I try to use `endl`:

```
Log(1)<<"My debug info: "<<otherVariable<<endl;
```

I get this error:

```
error C2678: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'Log' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

To solve this error I need to add another method to my class like this:

```
// For manipulators like endl
Log& operator<< (ostream& (*pf) (ostream&)) {
    if (msgLevel<=level) {
        cout << pf;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

But adding this method just to handle `endl` it seems a bit an overkill to me. Are there any better alternative?

Another alternative would be just to use "\n" instead of endl;

Comment: did you try std::endl

Comment: I am under using namespace std

Comment: I created a similar log class, but I used the destructor to output the line break

Comment: The proper way is a stream with a custom stream-buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `endl` is a function template, the simple version of `operator<<` isn't good enough, because there are multiple possible ways it could match by using different template arguments for `endl`.  Adding the second overload is probably the best you can do.

You could, however, factor out the common logic, like this:

```
template <class T>
Log& operator<<(const T& v){ return write(v); }

Log& operator<<(ostream& (*v)(ostream&)){ return write(v); }


template <typename T>
Log& write(const T &v)
{
    if (msgLevel<=level) {
        std::cout << v;
    }
    return *this;
}
```